# How to debug Jest unit test for a debounced function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, lodash, webstorm

I have the following function:

```
myFunction = _.debounce((viewport) => {
    ...
    otherFunction();
    ...
    someOtherFunction();
    ...
}, 650)
```

I'm trying to use jest to assert whether the `otherFunction` and `someOtherFunction` were run. In order to do this, I wanted to use WebStorm's debugger to check the function flow.

I've tried mocking the `_.debounce`:

```
_.debounce = jest.fn((fn) => fn);
```

Even though I tried adding a spy on the `myFunction` and jest says that the function ran, I can't make the debugger stop inside the function.

If I try to remove the `_.debounce` function, the debugger stops successfully.

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up moving my function logic to a new function: `myFunctionNoDebounce` and I kept the old myFunction only as a debounce wrapper. This way, I can test the `myFunctionNoDebounce` and I don't really need to test the `myFunction`.

This is certainly not the most elegant solution, but it works for now. I'm open to more suggestions to solve this problem in a better way.

```
myFunctionNoDebounce = (viewport) => {
    ...
    otherFunction();
    ...
    someOtherFunction();
    ...
}

myFunction = _.debounce((viewport) => {
    this.myFunctionNoDebounce(viewport)
}, 650)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but I believe you would have to execute the function in your mock implementation:

```javascript
_.debounce = jest.fn(fn => fn());
```